# application for sending message to tab from other tab or laptop only using WiFi without internet connection

Tags: android

I want to send text message from laptop or other tab and show them as big text on my tab, here's an illustration:

[image]

I can only think of some chat application but some that I know need internet connection and I can't make it show with bigger font.

Another option is using remote desktop so my tab will remote my laptop, and when I type something on my laptop, for example using notepad, I can also see it in my tab. I tried TeamViewer and it's perfect, but I still need internet connection.

Is there any software that can do this without internet connection?

Comment: @WingedPanther yes, 10.1" lavios tab

Comment: what about [realvnc](http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) ?

Comment: An idea: host an autorefreshing webpage on the laptop and open it with the browser of the tablet. Then you just need to change the content of the webpage.

Comment: Cannot try it currently (no second device/computer with ADB where I am now): `adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.SEND" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "Hello World" -t "text/plain"` For "big and colorful" you could enhance that with HTML. Not sure how this pops up; usually, the purpose of ACTION_SEND is to send something to someone else – so it might well open an "app-choser" to ask whether to send by SMS, mail, whatever. I might find something more suitable, if ADB is a way you'd accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)

VNC® remote access software for desktop and mobile platforms.

VNC enables you to remotely access and control your devices wherever you are in the world, whenever you need to. VNC has a widespread user base — from individuals to the world's largest multi-national companies — utilizing the technology for a range of applications.